# How to add button to Visual studio that kill process

Tags: visual-studio-2010, process, kill

I have to kill frequently few processes(services) on my developer machine to release memory used by it. And I cannot turn them off. At this moment I'm doing that manually in ProcessExplorer, but I think that there should be more automatic way.
I think that the best way is to add tool button to Visual Studio (I've added already such button that recycle IIS).

How to add tool button that will kill few processes by name (for example owstimer.exe and w3wp.exe). Or maybe you know an addin that could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a Macro in visual studio which enumerate processes and kill ones that correspond to your requirements.

Another solution is to create a custom .bat file with calls to `taskkill /im thexe.exe /f`. Then add in Visual Studio an entry in custom tools.

Instead of taskkill, you can also do a cleaner `net stop OWSTIMER` or `iisreset /stop`.

This will avoid killing the app, and shutdown properly the services.

A final word, some visual studio extensions (I think about WSPBuilder and/or CKSDev) add buttons that recycle SharePoint process.

Comment: thanks, taskkill works fine, and you are right that I should combine it with net stop.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to kill process from task manager then try this code:

```
 foreach (Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("yourprocess name"))
 { 
    try 
    {    
       p.Kill(); 
       p.WaitForExit(); // possibly with a timeout 
    } 
    catch (Win32Exception winException) 
    { 
       // process was terminating or can't be terminated - deal with it 
    } 

    catch (InvalidOperationException invalidException) 
    { 
      // process has already exited - might be able to let this one go 
    } 
 }
```

and add this two namespace:

```
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.ComponentModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a kill bat/cmd-file that you can executed from the tools-menue of visual studio.

[Sysinternals-Microsofts Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653) has a commandline exe pskill.exe that can do the job via commandline parameters ...